# removing implicit bound placed on a linear programming problem

Tags: scipy, linear-programming

I am trying to use the linear programming function from pythons scipy library however I am unable to remove a non negativity constrain placed on the variable. To demonstrate this consider the following code.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = [-1]
A = [[1]]
b = [-3]
print(linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=None))
```

it gives the following output:

```
     fun: 3.0
 message: 'Optimization failed. Unable to find a feasible starting point.'
     nit: 0
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: nan
```

This should be a formulation of the following problem: minimize c*x such that Ax≤b or equivalently minimize -1*x st. 1x≤-3. Hopefully I have done so correctly. Based on the current output I suspect that there is an additional constraint that x≥0. I don't know how to remove this constraint.

I have set the bounds to None with the understanding that this means no additional bounds are placed on the problem other than Ax≤b however there is clearly some other bound being placed on the problem. How can I remove this bound? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not the first one to be confused by this--the docstring should explain this better.

When you use `bounds=None`, you are telling `linprog` to use the default behavior, which is to assume the nonnegative constraint.  It is only by setting `bounds` to something else that the default behavior is changed.  In this case `bounds=(None, None)` will remove the bound on each variable.

```
In [40]: from scipy.optimize import linprog                                                                                                                                              

In [41]: c = [-1]                                                                                                                                                                        

In [42]: A = [[1]]                                                                                                                                                                       

In [43]: b = [-3]                                                                                                                                                                        

In [44]: print(linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(None, None)))                                                                                                                          
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 3.0
 message: 'The solution was determined in presolve as there are no non-trivial constraints.'
     nit: 0
   slack: array([0.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([-3.])
```